# Which are the Cloud service which we can use in our application ,which needs to store small files of max size 5 mb

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am working on an Application which would need to store small files (images , word doc, ppts and pdfs)

I want to use a cloud service which will enable me to do this without caring about Disk space and other stuffs.

1. It should have an Java api already built for it or else a simple
   Restful service.
2. Cost is not a big concern, performance is.

And to be more specific which one would be better: Amazon or Google Cloud storage? Any other better than these are also welcome.

This is not about the best one, I want to understand the pros and cons of these Cloud services.

Comment: This will probably get closed relatively soon for not being a question with a well defined answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only answer for the google app engine.
There are 3 possible options:

- App Engine Datastore (High Replication Datastore) [1]
- App Engine Blobstore [2]
- Google Cloud Storage [3]

The **Datastore** is fast, but has a size limit of 1mb, and that is to small for your files.

App Engines **Blobstore** is maybe what you are searching for. You can save many files and access them in a acceptable time.

**Google Cloud Storage** is slower, but has more features. You have to check if you need this features, if not, use Blobstore instead.

I choosed Cloud Storage, but my program was very slow because of the slow read/write time between GAE and GCS. I had to write a asynchronous save task with a cache to speed up my application (this is only available in GAEs backends).

[1] https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview

[2] https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview

[3] https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/overview